# Django: Using named urls in @login_required decorator

Tags: django, decorator, url-pattern

Most of `views` in my django app use `@login_required` decorator. Also, I have three different login urls. Views have corresponding login urls hardcoded into their `@login_required` decorators.

```
@login_required('myapp/logintype1'):
def usertype1_home(request):
    # Further dode
    # ...


@login_required('myapp/logintype2'):
def usertype2_home(request):
    # Further code
    # ...
```

Since the number of such views is quite large, whenever I change login url in `urls.py` I have to change `login-url` in all the decorators. I want to use something like `{% urls 'urlpatter1' %}` and `{% urls 'urlpatter2' %}`. Can I use `reverse`?

How I can use named url patterns instead of hard coding url patterns in `@login_required` decorator?

Comment: If you divided user group into several types, I'd also like to recommend you to use `user_passes_test` decorator. For example, `@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_type1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in the top of `views.py` after `import ...` statements add something like this

```
login_type1 = reverse_lazy('urlpatter1') # or LOGIN_TYPE1
login_type2 = reverse_lazy('urlpatter2') # or LOGIN_TYPE2
```

And use these variables later

```
@login_required(login_url=login_type1)
...
```

UPDATE: `reverse` was replaced with `reverse_lazy` as @Alasdair suggested. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) (2nd point).

Comment: This should work if you use `reverse_lazy` instead of `reverse`.

Comment: @Alasdair you were right. `lazy_reverse` worked. `reverse` shows error.